# Kali Linux .iso infected

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virus, iso-image

I wanted to try out Kali Linux, so I downloaded a VM and the Kali Linux ISO file from the official Kali website. It was running perfectly fine initially. However, after about a week, my laptop started freezing, so I ran Windows Defender, which flagged a severe threat from the Kali Linux ISO file. Additionally, the drive it was on seemed almost full. I assume this happened because the device got infected, and the drive filled up unexpectedly, as I had a good amount of GBs on that drive.

Is there any way to download the Kali Linux ISO file without the risk of viruses or malware? What can I do to ensure a clean and safe installation?

Comment: What threat did Defender say it found, exactly? My impression was that the whole **purpose** of Kali is to come with 'threats' bundled – just with their business end pointed away from the user, but they're 'threats' nevertheless...

Comment: I have been downloading Kali from the Kali website and using it as VM daily for 4 years. The Kali ISOs do not have viruses,

Comment: Another thing you might try is to download the Kali bare metal ISO. Then make a new VM out of that. This Kali VM I am posting from was built from the 2020 Kali ISO and then rolling upgrades applied. It is still running fine. The forensic and penetration tools work fine as well.

Comment: @u1686_grawity This is what the scan Detected: "Exploit:Java/CVE-2009-3867.gen!A" I am not too sure if it's harmless and it's bundled with the ISO file. I am still new to it and exploring it.

Comment: @John, Thank you! I will give it a try.

Comment: @NisNis: Was it detected inside e.g. Metasploit or something? Like I said, Kali ships a fair amount of tools that are literally meant to be exploits and such, so it would be very much expected for it.

Comment: @u1686_grawity, yes it was detected inside Metasploit-framework "kali-linux-2023.2a-installer-amd64.iso->pool\main\m\metasploit-framework\metasploit-framework_6.3.16-0kali1_amd64.deb->data.tar.xz->(xz)->./usr/share/metasploit-framework/data/exploits/CVE-2009-3867.jar->AppletX.class". And thank you for taking out the time to ask and answer :)

Answer (score 1):

> This is what the scan Detected: "Exploit:Java/CVE-2009-3867.gen!A"
>
> it was detected inside Metasploit-framework

That's normal then – having threats and exploits is **literally the purpose** of Metasploit. It's a tool that lets *you* run all sorts of exploits against systems (hence its name) and it's a standard part of the Kali Linux distribution.

Most anti-malware tools will detect the contents of Metasploit as harmful because if the file in question shows up on your machine *unknowingly,* chances are it's being used against you. But in this case, the .jar being detected is a deliberate part of the tool (it's even named "data/exploits/CVE-2009-3867.jar"), and the tool is a deliberate part of the distribution.